# How to use await mongoose without async

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, promise, discord.js

I have this code where I fetch a list of elements so I can make discordjs options with the mongoose data

```js
const items = require(‘./schema.js’)
    const items1 =  await items.find()


module.exports = {
    name: `buy`,
    timeout:15000,
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('buy')
.setDescription('buy an item!')
.addStringOption(option =>
    option
    .setName('itemid')
    .setDescription('the item you want to buy')
    .setRequired(true)
   /**   .addChoices(
        items1.forEach(item => {
            option.addChoice(`<:${item.EmojiName}:${item.EmojiID}>${item.ItemName} - <:bobux:809551218217058354>${item.Price} `,`${item.ItemID}` )
        })
    )
    */

    ),
```

When I do this, I get the error that you can’t use await outside of async. Does anyone have any solutions/alternatives to this code?

Thanks

Comment: The solution is to use `async`. You can't just export something from a file without it being a promise anyway.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in an async function, but that still requires await. How else can I use async await at the top and use that variable?

Comment: Top-level await is available in the newest nodejs. But other than that no way.

Comment: Have you tried using a callback function inside `addChoices()`

Comment: @Elitezen do you mean to make .addChoices async with a function? I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

The situation you're facing is more like a bad-design symptom than a limitation. What you are actually trying to do is "generating Discord commands — asynchronously — based on Mongoose data".

Well, just do that in the code. Don't try to mix and `export` synchronously an asynchronously generated thing. Rather simply make a function that generates it :

```js
const Item = require('./schema.js')

const itemToChoice = item => `<:${item.EmojiName}:${item.EmojiID}>${item.ItemName} - <:bobux:809551218217058354>${item.Price} `
const addItemsChoices = (option, items) => (
  items.reduce((option, item) => (
    option.addChoice(itemToChoice(item),`${item.ItemID}`)
  ), option)
)

module.exports = async () => {
  const items =  await Item.find()

  const command = {
    name: `buy`,
    timeout:15000,
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName('buy')
      .setDescription('buy an item!')
      .addStringOption(option => (
        addItemsChoices(
          option
            .setName('itemid')
            .setDescription('the item you want to buy')
            .setRequired(true),
          items
        )
      ))
  }

  return command
}
```

PS: for god sake, format your code

PS2: for god sake, remove [smart punctuation](https://bear.app/faq/How%20to%20disable%20smart%20quotes%20and%20dashes/#:%7E:text=Mac%20users%20can%20also%20disable,Use%20smart%20quotes%20and%20dashes.%E2%80%9D) on your computer